# Node.js Very Basic Local Authentication using Express Sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, authentication, basic-authentication

**Background** - I have been building a basic website using Node.js and now that I have got it up and running I need to establish a very basic form of local authentication to make the content secure to only a handful of trusted users (who I might choose to accept - I don't want a sign up feature). I have looked into a range of options including JSON Web Tokens, Cookies, etc, and have settled on using sessions, as they seem the simplest to setup. (This only has to be a basic short term security feature; it doesn't have to scale well or be a new standard in online security).

I have looked at a variety of online guides, and most of these rely on using a MongoDB database. I don't want to use this, as eventually I need to use PostgreSQL. A common theme has been to use `passport`:

- [Local Authentication Using Passport in Node.js](http://www.sitepoint.com/local-authentication-using-passport-node-js/).

It seems though that I may be able to avoid these, as done by the below example:

**Using `express-session` and `cookie-parser` with Express**

I have been trying to follow/modify the example from [Simple usage of express-session and cookie-parser with Express](http://code.runnable.com/U0tEnHwraXYyp-JG/simple-usage-of-express-session-and-cookie-parser-with-express-for-node-js) and have the following in my `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressSession = require('express-session');


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var private_info = require('./routes/private_info');

var app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(expressSession({secret:'somesecret'}));

app.use(bodyParser());

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  var html = '<form action="/" method="post">' +
      'Your name: <input type="text" name="userName"><br>' +
      '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
      '</form>';
  if (req.session.userName) {
    html += '<br>Your username from your session is: ' + req.session.userName;
  }
  res.send(html);
});


app.get('/private_info', function(req, res){
  var html = "You are not allowed to see this private info.";
  if (req.session.userName === "oliver") {
    html = 'See all this private info...<br/>DATA<br/>DATA<br/>User = ' + req.session.userName;
    res.render('private_info', { title: 'Private Info' });
  }
  res.send(html);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  req.session.userName = req.body.userName;
  res.redirect('/');
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/private_info', private_info);


// error handlers
    ... etc ...   

module.exports = app;
```

This works fairly well for my purposes (albeit there is an error message `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.`, but I can worry about that later). ***I would now like to incorporate this method into my main website***. However, the main website collects live data, and I don't know when/where/how to incorporate this into my current structure. The page I would like to secure has the following structure (found in `routes/predictions.js`):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var async = require("async");
var papa = require("papaparse");
var request_retry = require('requestretry');

// long series of function declarations and constructing a chain of call backs
function request_longshot_rob(first_data_list, res) {
    //Long series of functions producing a data object called data_for_client.
    res.render("predictions", {data: data_for_client});
}

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    request_longshot_rob(first_data_list, res);
});

module.exports = router;
```

How is the best way to incorporate this authentication request, especially if I want to secure maybe 5 pages and don't want to have to do something complicated on a case by case basis. I.e. I want the user's session ID/username to be verified, and if accepted, I would like the perform the script in `routes/predictions.js` as normal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

---

A typical `routes/` file, e.g. `routes/private_info` can generally have the following structure:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("private info page function");
    res.render('private_info', { title: 'Private Info' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: If it's very basic, can you just use express basicAuth() middleware? One shared password for all users or maybe a few different ones which you manually edit on a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I go describe how to to using Express, route, session and sequelize (PostgreSQL).

I Suggest you use Express Framework: http://expressjs.com. 
ORM Sequelize for PostgreSQL, MySQL: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/

The `app.get` method has three arguments http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.METHOD:

```
app.METHOD(path, callback [, callback ...]);
```

Can be used this way:

```
app.get(
'/path', 
middleware(),
function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

);

Follow this simple example (attention to middleware):

1) Create a front-end (EJS, Jade etc);

2) *Middleware* named authentication.js:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    if(!req.session.user) {
        return res.redirect('/');
    }
return next();
};
```

3) **Route** named login.js:

```
module.exports = function(app){

    module.exports = function (app){

        var login = app.controllers.login;

        app.get('/', login.index);
        app.post('/login', login.login);
        app.get('/logout', login.logout);
    };
```

4) **Controller** named login.js:

```
module.exports = function(app) {

  var sequelize = require('./libs/pg_db_connect');  

  var LoginController = {
    index: function(req, res) {
      res.render('login/index');
    },

    login: function(req, res) {

      var query = "SELECT * FROM foo"; // sql for user authentication

      sequelize.query(query, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}).then(function(user){    

        if (!user.length == 0){
          if (req.body.login == user[0].login  && req.body.senha === user[0].senha ){ 

            req.session.user = primeiroNome[0];
                res.redirect("/home");     
          } else {
            res.render("login/invalid_access");
          }
        } else {
          res.render("login/invalid_access");
        }

      });

    },

    logout: function(req, res) {
      req.session.destroy();
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  };

  return LoginController;

};
```

And in **all other routes** verify if user is logged in:

File *another_page_route.js*:

```
module.exports = function(app){

        var authentication = require('./middlewares/autenticador')
                , another_page = app.controllers.another_page;

        app.get('/home/action', authentication, another_page.action);   

};
```

Comment: A few questions about the proposed solution. **First**, where do I put all these files? Currently I have the following in my project: `app.js`, `node_modules/`, `public/`, `views/`, `bin/`, `package.json`, and `routes/`. Do steps 2/3/4 go in the `routes/` folder? **Second** in step (4) you're using SQL, how could I use a JSON file/object in the meantime (it's only a testing stage so I don't want to start hashing or encrypting stuff yet). **Third** in my (edited) question do you add the `another_page_route.js` content as the entirety of the file, or just append to `module.exports`?

Comment: First, where do I put all these files? R: This architecture it's supply by express, except the Middleware. Create a folder named Middleware and put the file there. Do steps 2/3/4 go in the routes/ folder? R: No, only step 3 and the last file named another_page_route.js. Second in step (4) you're using SQL[...]. R: Yes, sequelize suports object (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/). Third in my (edited) question [...]:R: it's only file route. Need to put in /route/.